# Enable a non-template member function iff it would typecheck

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, c++-templates

For example

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class foo
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

    T1 bar(); //Always exists
    decltype(t1(t2)) baz(); //Should only exist if t1(t2) is valid
};
```

If `baz` is invalid I still want the program to compile as long as nobody actually calls `baz`.

Comment: Have you experimented with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `baz` a template, such that if the return type is invalid the member will be SFINAE-d out rather than result in a hard error:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class foo
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

    T1 bar(); //Always exists

    template<typename T = T1>
    decltype(std::declval<T&>()(t2)) baz();
};
```

The `T` parameter is necessary to make the computed expression type-dependent, or else SFINAE doesn't apply. If you're worried that this implementation detail 'leaks' out and that someone might attempt `f.baz<int>()`, you can declare `baz` with `template<typename... Dummy, typename T = T1>` and enforce proper usage with e.g. `static_assert( sizeof...(Dummy) == 0, "Incorrect usage" );` in the function body. Both approaches do make it harder to take the address of the member: it should look like e.g. `&foo<T, U>::baz<>`.

Another approach is to introduce a class template specialization:

```
template<typename...> struct void_ { using type = void; };

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename = void>
class foo {
    // version without baz
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class foo<T1, T2, typename void_<decltype(std::declval<T1&>()(std::declval<T2>()))>::type> {
    decltype(std::declval<T1&>()(std::declval<T2>())) baz();
};
```

In this case `&foo<T, U>::baz` is fine for taking the address of the member (assuming it is present of course). Code that is common to both specialization can be factored out in a common base, and if there is a worry that the additional template parameter that is introduced as an implementation detail might leak it is possible to have a 'real' `foo` taking only two template parameters in turn inheriting from such an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is for C++11, I think it's worth providing the modern C++20 approach as well, using constraints:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <class T1, class T2>
class foo
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

    T1 bar();
    auto baz() requires std::invocable<T1, T2>;
};
```

`baz()` has a [deduced return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction) so that you don't get a compiler error due to `decltype(t1(t2))` being invalid. As a result, it has to be defined prior to its use, but since `foo` is a class template, that's usually the case anyway.

`baz()` is also given [a trailing requires-clause](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_clauses), which "disables" the member if the condition is false. `std::invocable` isn't *exactly* the same as checking whether `t1(t2)` is valid, but if you need *exactly* that check, you can also write your own concept:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Args>
concept callable_with = requires (T& t, Args&... args) {
    // TODO: maybe use perfect forwarding here?
    //       once again, that would not be *exactly* t1(t2) anymore
    t(args...);
};
```

And then:

```cpp
auto baz() requires callable_with<T1, T2>;
```